# How can I zero pad a particular field in a text file?

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I have a file like this:

```
123123213,456,be
124243233,4346,ytr
123123123,436535,uytr
324234324,322,yt
234324323,32,tyutr
```

I want to zero-pad the middle field to give the result:

```
123123213,00000456,be
124243233,00004346,ytr
123123123,00436535,uytr
324234324,00000322,yt
234324323,00000032,tyutr
```

How do I make a script that woud do this?

I've seen an example like this

```
awk '{ $6=sprintf("%06s", $6); print $0}'
```

but I don't really understand it and thus can't get it working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F , '{ printf "%i,%08i,%s\n" , $1 , $2 , $3 }' file
```

Comment: Ok, `-F ,` tells `awk` to use `,` as field separator, then it prints all the three fields (`$1`, `$2` and `$3`) with a custom format: `"%i,%08i,%s\n"`, `%i` is for integers, `%08i` sets the field width to 8 left-padding with zeros and is `%s` for strings. For more info see `man printf` or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf). Hope this helps you.

Comment: i need to change the comma seperator into a cedilla using the unput $'\xE7' but when i use    printf "%i "$'\xE7'" %08i\n" , $1, $2 it doesnt come out correct. any ideas?

Comment: Something like: `awk -F , '{ printf "%i\xe7%08i\xe7%s\n" , $1 , $2 , $3 }' file`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged your question `[sed]`, here is a `sed` version based on the script [here](http://www.rtfiber.com.tw/~changyj/sed/html/p.20010907a.html).

```
sed 's/[^,][^,]*/\n0000000&/2;s/\n[^,]*\(.\{8\}\),/\1,/' inputfile
```

Explanation:

- a field consists of a group of one or more non-commas: **`[^,][^,]*`** (this could also be written as **`[^,]\+`**)
- substitute for the second field (match) (**`s///2`**) a newline, a bunch of zeros and the contents of the match: **`\n0000000&`** (the newline is used to mark the beginning of the field for the next step)
- now match the newline, zero or more non-commas and exactly eight **`\{8\}`** of any character (capturing those characters **`\(\)`** ) followed by a comma
- substitute the captured characters **`\1`** for the match, this removes the temporary newline and the excess zeros

The way this works is to add excess zeros at the beginning of the field then chop off all but the

Answer (score 0):

the command in your question is correct just need some update.

`awk '{ $6=sprintf("%0.8s", $6); print $0}'`

also to change output field seperator use:

`awk '{ OFS="\xE7"; $6=sprintf("%0.8s", $6); print $0}'`